# How to delete the specific row of n-dimensional array in Julia?

Tags: arrays, julia

I want to have a function which returns a new array with sub-arrays along an axis deleted in Julia.

More specifically, given an array(which may be n-dimensional), delete the row(s) we specify along a designated dimension and return a new array.

In Python, we have such a function, namely `numpy.delete`.

If 2-dimension, I could have the following function.

```
function delete(array::Array{<:Real,2}, obj::Int64, idx::Int64)
 """
 obj : row to be deleted
 idx : dimension(row if 1, column otherwise)
 """
if idx == 1
 new_array = array[1:size(array,1) .!= obj, : ]
else
 new_array = array[:, 1:size(array)[2] .!= obj]
end

 return new_array
end
```

Then, I can get desired result, for example

```
>a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
 3×3 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3
 4  5  6
 7  8  9
>delete(a, 2, 2)
 3×2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  3
 4  6
 7  9
```

However, how to extend this function to the **n**-dimension? In addition, I also want to delete multiple rows simultaneously, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not aware of a specific function for what you need, but you can try this:

```
function delete(array::Array, rows::AbstractVector{Int}, dim::Int)
    sel = Any[Colon() for i in 1:ndims(array)]
    sel[dim] = setdiff(axes(array, dim), rows)
    array[sel...]
end

delete(array::Array, rows::Int, dim::Int) = delete(array, [rows], dim)
delete(array::Array, rows::AbstractVector{Bool}, dim::Int) = delete(array, findall(rows), dim)
delete(array::Array, rows::Colon, dim::Int) = delete(array, axes(array, dim), dim)
```

It does not do argument checking (so invalid or duplicate indices will silently be discarded), but it is simple to add if you need it. Also you could consider creating a `view` instead of a copy.

**EDIT**:

The core function can be written in a bit shorter form:

```
function delete(array::Array, rows::AbstractVector{Int}, dim::Int)
    rng = setdiff(axes(array, dim), rows)
    array[ntuple(i -> i == dim ? rng : (:), ndims(array))...]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

This is by modifying the code for [`eachslice`](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/29749/files#diff-ec1aa8d7e797ec17b96826e6347377b6R443) (from [v1.1.0](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/commit/6175bd9e3996f55f3e2a7bf8bf350bb7c96980ad))

```
function delete_dim(A::AbstractArray, index, dim)
    idx1, idx2 = ntuple(d->(:), dim-1), ntuple(d->(:), ndims(A)-dim)
    view(A, idx1..., axes(A, dim) .!= index,idx2...)
end

let a = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
    delete_dim(a, 2, 2)
end
```

EDIT: `1:size(A, dim)` → `axes(A, dim)` per @bogumil

Comment: A small comment - AFAIK it is better to write `axes(A, dim)` than `1:size(A, dim)` (like in my solution) as the array does not have to be `1`-indexed in general.